# What are the caveats when leaving apache with ALL(ALL) = ALL?

Tags: php, apache, security, sudo

I'm creating a web app (php) that handles the creation of Drupal sites on a live server.

The system is able to create new sites and give some maintenance on existing ones. And, as this is a web-hosting environment, each folder may belong to a different user.

In order to do that properly I need to let the `apache` user run some commands as some other user.

What I do to create new files (and interact with `git`/`drush`/etc) is something similar to:

```
$some_command = `echo "PASSWD" | sudo -u USER -S do_something 2>&1; echo $?;`;
```

I already have a set of commands on the `sudoers` file that the `apache` user can run as the `git` user.

My issue now is that I need to let `apache` run as ANY user that may have a hosting account on the server.

My idea was to create a `apache ALL=(ALL) ALL` entry on the `sudoers` file. I would still leave all those commands asking for the users password.

With that in mind, is this wise to go with this approach? And if not, maybe I could apply the "allow all" policy only to the users that have a hosting account. If so, how do I narrow the policy to only one *group*?

Thanks

---

**Edit:** I though on using **[suPHP](http://www.suphp.org/Home.html)** for this, as it allows apache to run each PHP script as its owner. But I would still need to run some other commands as another user (as creating files in someone else's home folder/public_html), so it seems that it isn't an option.

Comment: At first thought it may be a bad idea.  Do all of the users' sites also run as Apache?  If so consider using something that can switch users for PHP based on the owner of the script.  I think that would bypass all security as anyone could write a PHP script to read or edit other users' files.

Comment: Hmm. True. I thought on using `suPHP`, but for that I would have to do a LOT of changes on my hosting environment. Do you have any suggestions on that?

Comment: And even with the PHP files being run by its owner I would still need the option to run commands as another user, as the main idea here is to create files/folders in someone else's home folder (public_html, etc).

Comment: I use suPHP on one of my servers and would recommend it.  I wouldn't go without such a thing in a shared environment.  Even if you trust each of your users personally, the person who "hacks" into their accounts can and probably will take advantage of an insecurity such as that.  You will have to edit each vhost to set their appropriate settings, but once you make the initial changes and create a vhost template with the suPHP config, its no big deal.  I just add this to each vhost `<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
        suPHP_UserGroup jdoe jdoe
    </IfModule>`  Then PHP runs as jdoe for that vhost.

Comment: The key there is that since each user's PHP script runs as their uid, they won't be able to take advantage of the apache user's `sudo` power.  You can still make a user with those additional permissions, but your users won't be able to take advantage of it.

Comment: I haven't thought about creating another "sudoer" user and running my application as it. Seems like a pretty good idea indeed. Can you elaborate an answer with that, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our discussion in comments, I would advise installing something like `suPHP` so that each of your user's scripts are owned by their actual user and not Apache.

I figure you are having this issue is (maybe) because you want to be able to perform the administrative functions of other user's sites from a web interface.  If you have a generic user like `apache` that other users can run scripts as, allowing that user automatic `sudo` permission is a bad idea since it could easily be exploited to gain unauthorized access.

To get around that, make sure you run your administrative functions as a special admin user that has permission to modify other people's files.  Also make sure to `chown` any files you create as the appropriate user so they can read/write them.  And as long as no other users can access that admin account or run PHP scripts as them, you should be much safer.

If you're running the admin functions from the console then it should be even easier, otherwise just set up a suPHP user to run your master functions from the web and use good credentials for the account.

Doing something like that will be more secure and should allow you to do everything you need without opening things up more than necessary.